# Do I need any other wso2 product or ESB is just fine?

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I'm working on a master's degree project which the main goal is wso2 study.

Through wso2 I need to be able to:

- Do protocol Bridging (eg: rest to soap);
- Apply data transformation (apply xslt on xml);
- Content based routing;
- Load balancing;
- Create authentication and authorization layer to legacy services (authentication via oauth 1.0a);
- Exception shielding;
- Service monitoring;
- Services lifecycle control;

So, my question is: do I need any other wso2 product, or ESB is just fine? For example to implement the security layer and all the load balance stuff do I need to add wso2 identity server and wso2 elastic load balancer?

Or even more: do I need to extend the esb by writing custom code to solve any of this issues? In which cases extend the esb is the only way to go?

I hope to do not be naive trying to solve all this complicated issues, but I'm  kinda lost on this big swiss knife that wso2 is.

Thanks

Comment: For servicelfecycle control you may need GREG. But it would be clear , if you explain your project in abstract

Comment: In abstract there are two main goals: 
-  centralize all services already available; 
-  expose private services by providing the missing security layer. 

The rest of the issues that I have described will be implemented but just as a proof of concept, i. e.,  to prove that with wso2 is possible to have all this features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find my answer..

1. Do protocol Bridging (eg: rest to soap  --->  ESB
2. Apply data transformation (apply xslt on xml) ---->   ESB
3. Content based routing  ----> ESB
4. Load balancing  --->  ESB can be used. But i prefer Apache HTTP and Nginx. They are more intended for that purpose
5. Create authentication and authorization layer to legacy services (authentication via oauth 1.0a)   -->   ESB can be used.  But you need an OAuth2 Authorization  server for token validation.  Also,  XACML PDP for policy validation. Both are available with Identity Server. According to the Carbon,  you can install those features with ESB as well. But it is not recommended much. Please see more details from [here](http://xacmlinfo.org/2014/10/24/authorization-for-apis-with-xacml-and-oauth-2-0/)
6. Exception shielding ---> ESB
7. Service monitoring ----> ESB  can be used. But if more, you can use BAM
8. Services lifecycle control ---> ESB can be used. If needed more,  you can install G-reg features

I think.  It is only enough to use WSO2 ESB and WSO2 IS for this purpose. Sometime you may need to write some code.  But it is easy as there are lot of samples are available freely.

Comment: But I still missing one thing: is OAuth2 an imposition of wso2esb or I can use 1.0a? Because we already have an oauth1.0a infrastructure mounted and it would be nice if we can use what we already have.